# aufwecken vs wecken Unterschied

Tags: meaning

Servus miteinander. 
Auf meine Frage: " ich hoffe ich habe dich gerade nicht aufgeweckt " ist mir geantwortet worden: "du hast mich nicht geweckt" .
Deswegen gehe ich davon aus, dass ich anstatt von aufwecken lieber wecken hätte verwenden sollen.
Ist es richtig? Wenn ja, warum?

Comment: Aufwecken ist näher am Geschehen. Beides kann auch gemischt verwendet werden, je nachdem, wie man selbst die Intensität der Störung durch das Wecken wahrnimmt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mein Empfinden sagt folgendes:

Beide Sätze sind akzeptabel: "Ich hoffe, ich habe dich gerade nicht aufgeweckt" und "Ich hoffe, ich habe dich gerade nicht geweckt".

Dabei hat der erste Satz einen eher umgangssprachlichen Klang, der zweite könnte auch in einem Roman oder Theaterstück mit sorgfältigerer Sprachverwendung stehen. Aber der Unterschied ist ein sehr feiner.

Der Hintergrund ist, dass "aufgeweckt" sich - ursprünglich jedenfalls - mehr auf das Resultat des Weckens bezieht (jemand wurde geweckt und ist nun auf). "Geweckt" blickt mehr auf den Vorgang des Weckens bzw. des Gewecktwerdens. (Ähnlicher Unterschied wie beim Verbalaspekt der slawischen Sprachen, wo dies aber grammatikalisiert ist.)

Comment: Endlich Mal eine Antwort, mit der ich etwas anfangen kann! Herzlichen Dank!

Comment: Was ist daran umgangssprachlich, hat die Einschaetzung mit "auf" als umgangssprachlich "wach" zu tun? Der feine Unterschied ist mMn. die Anregung des Kreislaufs beim Aufstehen (oder beim Augenaufschlagen?).

Comment: vgl. *ein aufgewecktes Kerlchen*

Comment: Hmmmmmmm. Ich denke, dass in deine Analyse das Adjektiv *aufgeweckt* in seiner anderen Bedeutung (auf die vectorious anspielt) zu sehr hineingespielt hat. Zwar sind *aufwecken* und *wecken* leicht anders, aber *aufwecken* blickt meines Erachtens nicht mehr auf das Ergebnis …

Comment: @TomasWalek Wenn dir die Antwort gefällt, gib lieber +1 statt dich zu bedanken, das ist hier bei SE der Weg, wie man sich bedankt.

Answer (score 1):

> Habe ich dich geweckt?

... den Schlaf unterbrechen, verwende ich, wenn der andere noch im Bett ist und gerade erst aufsteht/wach wird.

> habe ich dich aufgeweckt?

... der andere ist schon wach, z.B. beim Frühstücken, und ich frage, weil ich wissen will, ob er meinetwegen aufstand.